# C# application and assembly hell!

Tags: c#, dll, installation

I have created a C# project on my home computer with Windows 7, VS 2008 and using .net framework 2.0. My app is using "Irklang" sound library. Using InnoSetup 5 i have created setup for my app. Setup includes all needed files, it installs them well but when i install my app on some other computer i got some confusing errors. First one looks like this:

[image]

When i create install script flaging "irklang.dll" with "regserver" (to be registered during setup), i got this error during installation of my program: "Unable to register DLL/OCX: RegSrv32 failed with exit code 0x4". Message got standard "Abort, Ignore, Retry" buttons, but, as always, "Retry" won't fix it.

What should i do? How to fix this error which shouldn't even bother average programmer?

This is my Inno setup instalation file:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!
[CustomMessages]
dotnetmissing=This setup requires the .NET Framework v2.0. Please download and install the .NET Framework v.2 and run this setup again. Do you want to download the framework now?

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{10087152-8A1D-4C0B-9BFC-E463C2F8E3C0}
AppName=Kucni rad
AppVersion=1.5
;AppVerName=Kucni rad 1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\Kucni rad
DefaultGroupName=Kucni rad
OutputDir=C:\Users\Boza\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes



[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
    ErrorCode: Integer;
    NetFrameWorkInstalled : Boolean;
    Result1 : Boolean;
begin

    NetFrameWorkInstalled := RegKeyExists(HKLM,'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v2.0');
    if NetFrameWorkInstalled =true then
    begin
        Result := true;
    end;

    if NetFrameWorkInstalled = false then
    begin
        NetFrameWorkInstalled := RegKeyExists(HKLM,'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v2.0');
        if NetFrameWorkInstalled =true then
        begin
            Result := true;
        end;

        if NetFrameWorkInstalled =false then
            begin
                //Result1 := (ExpandConstant('{cm:dotnetmissing}'), mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = idYes;
                Result1 := MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:dotnetmissing}'),
                        mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = idYes;
                if Result1 =false then
                begin
                    Result:=false;
                end
                else
                begin
                    Result:=false;
                    ShellExec('open',
                    'http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/7/567758a3-759e-473e-bf8f-52154438565a/dotnetfx.exe',
                    '','',SW_SHOWNORMAL,ewNoWait,ErrorCode);
                end;
            end;
    end;
end;


[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\Sounds"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Boza\Desktop\Novi kucnirad\kucnirad\bin\Debug\kucnirad.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Boza\Desktop\Novi kucnirad\kucnirad\bin\Debug\Sounds\*"; DestDir: "{app}\Sounds"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\Boza\Desktop\Novi kucnirad\kucnirad\bin\Debug\ikpMP3.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion regserver
Source: "C:\Users\Boza\Desktop\Novi kucnirad\kucnirad\bin\Debug\irrKlang.NET2.0.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion regserver

; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Kucni rad"; Filename: "{app}\kucnirad.exe"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Kucni rad}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Kucni rad"; Filename: "{app}\kucnirad.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\kucnirad.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,Kucni rad}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

EDIT:
I GOT IT! IT'S NOT PROBLEM WITH MY APP, IT'S PROBLEM WITH DOWNLOADED DLL ITSELF! It seems that IrrKlang.dll version 1.3 (the newest version, i used) is causeing the problems! Version 1.1 is working just fine!

Comment: Regsvr32 requires admin rights when the installer is running. Can you get a .net version of that object?

Comment: You can get a lot more information from the fusion log. If the exception detail doesn't include fusion log information, you can get it through other means, such as those described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx

Comment: This kind of thing can also happen if you're trying to install a 64-bit DLL on a 32-bit machine, or the other way around (a 32-bit DLL using the 64-bit tools).

Answer (score 0):

RegSrv32 is for COM dll's and from the looks of it the irklang.dll is a .NET dll.

.NET DLLs can be registered using RegAsm.exe if they need to be available for COM.

Comment: Please, come again?! :) Really, i have no idea about registering dll-s, mostly everything just worked when setup does it's job...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this is on Windows Vista or 7?  Add to your InnoSetup file the requirement that the user be an Administrator.

Namely, add "PrivilegesRequired=admin" in the script's [Setup] section.

Comment: It works on Windows 7 cause it's created, build, compiled on Win7. It won't work on WinXP!

Comment: @Nemo Also the reason it works on your machine is because the DLL is already registered on your machine.

Comment: @Nemo Like I said, throw "PrivilegesRequired=admin" into the script's [Setup] section.

Comment: @Nemo Also, I wouldn't be throwing `ignoreversion` all over the place (even though you are not changing anything system-wide).  It might make upgrades difficult.

Comment: No,"PrivilegesRequired=admin" won't change anything! :\ Still won't work on WinXp! Error while registering dll (mentioned in my question) remains! RegSrv32 - error 0x4!

Comment: You should not be trying to registering native dotnet dlls So I would remove the regserver flag from the irrKlang.NET2.0 line.

Answer (score 0):

The error message does say that it can not load IrrKlang.NET2.0 **or one of its dependencies** , so you will probably find that it needs other dlls to work, which happen to be one your machine.

Best to go back to where you got this dll which should have this documented.

Update.

Apparently it needs MSVCR80.DLL and MSVCM80.DLL [see here](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/faq.html#dotnetonotherpc)

Comment: I know that! I have installed "vcredist_x86", i also have VS2008 on my testing computer - no luck! :\

Comment: You could try downloading and running Process Monitor from sysinternals. This will show you any files that your application is trying to load and might point to other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking through Google and came across [this forum post](http://www.ambiera.com/forum.php?t=887).  It seems that, depending on which version of the library you're using, there may be a known issue with .NET 2.0.  They suggested adding this to your app.config:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```